# Unable to strip characters from DB return value

Tags: python, sql-server, numpy

I am relatively new to python and am having some difficulties.
I am using pyodby to exec a stored procedure in sql-server.
The result doesnt seem to come back as an integer as expected, but rather the number of rows in parenthesis. IE: (322,)
When I try to strip out the values I get an error. I assume I have the wrong data-type? Thanks for the help

**TypeError: expected string or buffer**

```
import pyodbc
import re
import numpy as np
sqlquery = "exec MyDB.dbo.spRowCounts"
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=1.2.3.4\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=MyDB;UID=MYUSER;PWD=MYPASSWORD')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
rows = cursor.execute(sqlquery)

print rows;
for row in rows:
    print row
    queuerow = row
    print queuerow
    rowd = re.sub(r'\D', "", queuerow)
    print rowd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If queuerow is '(322,)' when printed it means it's a tuple, so obviously a regex can't modify it, you just make queuerow[0]. When you have a TypeError the best way to debug is simply to use the built-in type().

Comment: that worked perfectly! Thanks. I have to get used to these datatypes. (coming from Perl)